# Setting git committer's name to environment variable in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In jenkins declarative pipeline, I am trying to get the name of git committer and then set it to en environment variable. Getting part works fine, however, no matter which syntax I tried, it doesn't work.

For example I tried `script` block:

```
script {
    env.GIT_CULPRIT = sh('git log --format="%ae" | head -1 | awk -F"@" \'{print $1}\'')
    echo "culprit: ${env.GIT_CULPRIT}"
}
```

Output:

> [Pipeline] echo
>   culprit: null

Tried `environment` block (inside `dir` block):

```
environment {
    env.GIT_CULPRIT = sh(script: 'git log --format="%ae" | head -1', returnStdout: true)
    echo "culprit: ${env.GIT_CULPRIT}"
}
```

Output:

> WorkflowScript: 33: Missing required parameter: "name" @ line 33, column 21.
>                          environment {
>                          ^
>
> WorkflowScript: 33: Missing required parameter: "value" @ line 33, column 21.
>                          environment {
>                          ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "[Jenkins Pipeline - set and use environment variables](https://code-maven.com/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables)", the second approach should work.

Except:

> The above only works when the environment section is inside a "`stage`" but would yield "`null`" for `WORKSPACE` outside the stages.

Note that in the step section, that environment variable is referenced as `${VAR}`, not `${env.VAR}`

Comment: the thing is, I cannot execute `git log --format="%ae"` from outside of `dir` because it should be executed from the dir git initailized in.

Comment: @Waqas Coud you assign the result of git log executed in dir to a variable, and then define an environment variable in a stage, with the value of that local variable?